# How to fix "Repeat one word in all Title from all pages index by google?"

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

All pages of my site index by google With a duplicate word in the title!
I use joomla 3.9 for my website. And Me followed all SEO rules. (title for all page and menu,alias,meta dec and meta keyword)
But, in all pages index by google this word is duplicate in title : "خانه"
how fix that?  Where is the problem?

You can see this photo :  duplicate word is : "خانه" 
https://ibb.co/TP9GxQT

Yes i know, But  "خانه" doesn't site name! this is first menu name! and Repeat in all title! How Repeat first menu name in all title in google?!!

Comment: Just so you know, [joomla.se] Stack Exchange is a dedicated q&a site for Joomla support. (Neil answers questions there too.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla Global Configuration, you can enable the Site Name to appear before or after the Page Title on each page.

Comment: Yes i know, But  "خانه" doesn't site name! this is first menu name! and Repeat in all title! How Repeat first menu name in all title in google?!!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in my site but i finally find it!
you need to check your home page ,if "خانه" has h1 tag remove it!
it's funny but my problem was issue when remove it!

Comment: If you are able to provide Joomla support please join us at [joomla.se] and see if you can help us to resolve some questions.